# Undefined 'id' attribute in button element which is defined in code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I am currently trying to create an extension for visual studio, I have got the first button in the XML file working, however the second button throws me an error, however they are both the same except the `ButtonText`, `LocCanonicalName` and `id` inside of the button. Any help would be appreciated.

Error: `Undefined 'id' attribute 'TestTwo' in a <Button> element` - Like 29

Main part of the code:

```
<Commands package="CppAssist">
    <Groups>
      <Group guid="CppAssist" id="MyMenuGroup" priority="0x0600">
        <Parent guid="VSMainMenu" id="Tools"/>
      </Group>
    </Groups>

    <!--This section defines the elements the user can interact with, like a menu command or a button
        or combo box in a toolbar. -->
    <Buttons>
        <Button guid="CppAssist" id="Test" priority="0x0100" type="Button">
            <Parent guid="CppAssist" id="MyMenuGroup" />
            <Icon guid="ImageCatalogGuid" id="Add" />
            <CommandFlag>IconIsMoniker</CommandFlag>
            <Strings>
                <ButtonText>Test</ButtonText>
                <LocCanonicalName>.Tools.Test</LocCanonicalName>
            </Strings>
        </Button>

        <Button guid="CppAssist" id="TestTwo" priority="0x0100" type="Button"> <!-- Line 29: ERROR -->
            <Parent guid="CppAssist" id="MyMenuGroup" />
            <Icon guid="ImageCatalogGuid" id="Add" />
            <CommandFlag>IconIsMoniker</CommandFlag>
            <Strings>
                <ButtonText>Another Test</ButtonText>
                <LocCanonicalName>.Tools.TestTwo</LocCanonicalName>
            </Strings>
        </Button>
    </Buttons>
  </Commands>

  <Symbols>
    <GuidSymbol name="CppAssist" value="{a71b9f85-5b58-44aa-b87d-5b50fbd99202}">
      <IDSymbol name="MyMenuGroup" value="0x0001" />
      <IDSymbol name="Test" value="0x0100" />
      <IDSymbol name="TestTwo" value="0x0100" />
    </GuidSymbol>
  </Symbols>
```

Answer (score 5):

I worked out how to do this, inside the `<Symbols>` element, increase the `<IDSymbol>` `value` by 1.

```
<Symbols>
    <GuidSymbol name="CppAssist" value="{a71b9f85-5b58-44aa-b87d-5b50fbd99202}">
      <IDSymbol name="MyMenuGroup" value="0x0001" />
      <IDSymbol name="Test" value="0x0100" />
      <IDSymbol name="TestTwo" value="0x0200" />
    </GuidSymbol>
  </Symbols>
```

Comment: The reason why your fix works is that `IDSymbol` should have unique value within the `GuidSymbol` element. In your case, Test and TestTwo shared the same value and the compiler/runtime couldn't tell which of these would you refer to. Similarly, if the values were `4129` and `0x1021`, both evaluating to the same decimal, the error would appear again. The error messages in the Visual Studio are not really helpful.